# How to access non containerised DB on remote IP from a docker container?

Tags: java, spring, docker, networking, jersey

I am trying to package Java web services in Docker. I have a postgres DB hosted on a VM (non-containerised) and the code in the docker container is unable to connect to the database. How to do that?

Comment: Can you share the `docker run` command that you are currently using?

Comment: using a database url like `spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://nameOfDomain:3306/nameOfDB`? Anyways show us the code or get ready for downvotes.

Comment: docker run -p 80:8080 {{imageId}}

Comment: are both (app and database docker container) running on the same virtual machine?

Comment: The code runs perfectly fine when hosted in tomcat on my local machine... if deployed in a docker container it fails to connect to the DB

Comment: @JAsgarov no they are on seperate machines

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically `spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://yourIpAddress/nameOfDB` should work.

But database don't run on 8080 so you need to bind the port of database (for postgres 5432, for mysql 3306) and I wouldnt bind it to 80, where everything is listening.

If you are running postgres it will be listening on 5432 so you can do `docker run -p 8082:5432 postgres`

Then you should be able to connect to your host computer via `jdbc:postgresql://yourIpAddress:8082/nameOfDB`

This all assumes nothing else jumps in the way, like firewalls or whatnot. I also don't know how you configured your virtual machine. In general you should practice connecting them on the same machine to get the idea first.

Comment: Good answer from the Java POV, but his main problem is that he has no route form the docker bridge network to the external IP address where his DB is hosted.

Comment: @NeoAnderson is correct I am looking for a way to connect to the external IP

Comment: You should be able to use putty to connect from windows to Linux https://superuser.com/questions/1354966/connect-using-windows-ssh-to-another-windows